# Transpose a dynamic range data from vertical to horizontal format

Tags: excel, vba

This is the data given to me, you can see the columns B and C are similar in all aspects except the Export items data:

[image]

This is the data which is transposed to horizontal way without VBA code:

[image]

Only issue is whenever i try doing it via VBA code, i don't get the remaining data as it is.
it comes in as jumbled.

```
  Sub test2()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim toWs As Worksheet
    Dim vDB, vR()
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, k As Long

    Set Ws = Sheets(1)
    Set toWs = Sheets(2)

    Set rngDB = Ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    vDB = rngDB

    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    c = UBound(vDB, 2)

    For j = 2 To c
        n = n + 1
        'ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 4, 1 To n)
        ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 5, 1 To n)
        vR(1, n) = vDB(1, j)
        vR(2, n) = vDB(2, j)
        vR(3, n) = vDB(3, j)
        vR(4, n) = vDB(4, j)
        vR(5, n) = vDB(r, j) 'added insurance
        'For i = 5 To r
        For i = 5 To r - 1
            If vDB(i, j) <> "" Then
                n = n + 1
                ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 5, 1 To n)
                vR(4, n) = vDB(i, j)
            End If
        Next i
    Next j

    With toWs
        k = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
        '.Range("a" & k).Resize(n, 4) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
        .Range("a" & k).Resize(n, 5) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you using the long, manual way for learning purposes?

Comment: Yes long process , but this code given by @Dy.Lee has come up good when i have small set of  data, but then now i have a long range of data and use of loop is something i'm really bad on.
rngDB.Transpose() is not being used bcz of the reason i have data which is dynamic in nature and simply transposing data will not work, or else i cud have done manual transpose only.

Comment: Did the answer work for you?

Comment: @AmitShah, The form of your data has changed again. The data you asked before is now completely different. You should ask questions consistently about the exact type of data and the type of transformation. The previous code is not applicable to this data.

Comment: It is rude to reveive an answer and to not acknowledge it in any way. If the solution works for you, accept the as answer. If it does not work, explain why.

Comment: I'm really sorry for late reply, we have a festival today, so couldn't reply.
I didn't review any code till now, will sit on it in sometime and let you guys know about it.
@Dy.Lee Yes this data is different , but i wanted to simplify this huge question and let everyone understand it better, maybe i confused everyone in the process of doing so.
The data for " Export items" as we can see in the images , belongs to same group(Shipping Bill no) [Row 4].
Thus, the 2nd ROW in sheet 2 should only have export items as different rest can be left blank or get copied as it is.

Comment: I'm also trying to make a Button, which can then differentiate between (SB No's) having "Single export item" or "multiple export item" , which will make the sheet look cooler and be more presentable.
Also if you guys have seen it,  we can create a Button for "ITC(HS)" which can differentiate between multiple Shipping bills.

Comment: Is it possible that whenever more than 1 value in any set field , lets say here "Export Items" , then it should create a new row in Sheet 2 and be transposed as seen in the pic.
Bcz not only there will multiple Export items but also multiple "ITC(HS)" number for a particular Shipping Bill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Test2()

    Dim i&, j&, vIn, vOut

    With ThisWorkbook

        vIn = .Worksheets(1).Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Value2

        ReDim vOut(1 To UBound(vIn, 2), 1 To UBound(vIn, 1))

        For i = 1 To UBound(vIn, 1)
            For j = 1 To UBound(vIn, 2)
                vOut(j, i) = vIn(i, j)
            Next
        Next

        .Worksheets(2).Range("a1").Resize(UBound(vOut, 1), UBound(vOut, 2)) = vOut

    End With    

End Sub
```

A more generic, reusable, and functional way to do it would be like so...

```
Sub Test3()

    Dim vIn

    With ThisWorkbook        
        vIn = .Worksheets(1).[a1].CurrentRegion.Value2
        .Worksheets(2).[a1].Resize(UBound(vIn, 2), UBound(vIn, 1)) = MyTranspose(vIn)            
    End With

End Sub

Function MyTranspose(vIn)

    Dim i&, j&, vOut

    ReDim vOut(1 To UBound(vIn, 2), 1 To UBound(vIn, 1))        
    For i = 1 To UBound(vIn, 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(vIn, 2)
            vOut(j, i) = vIn(i, j)
        Next
    Next    
    MyTranspose = vOut

End Function
```

Comment: This code is unable to next line , if i have fresh data, i.e., each time i entry new data , the new data seems to override the previous one

Comment: Please clarify what your question is. The above code works perfectly for your initial question.

Comment: But if i have to enter new set of data , then it overrides previous data.
it's not being entered into the next line.
please help me out.

Comment: I have sent you mail with all the details and file too.

Answer (score 0):

**Transpose data**

tltr; and I didn't follow the prior discussion ... but why not just apply `Application.Transpose()` to the entire data set instead of executing inner and outer loops?

```
Option Explicit                                               ' declaration head of code module

Sub TransposeData()
    '[1]get data and assign them to variant 1-based 2-dim array
        Dim v ' As Variant
        v = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value2            ' << change to your source worksheet's CodeName

    '[2]transpose data and write to target sheet - e.g. Code(Name) Sheet2  
        Sheet2.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(v, 2), UBound(v, 1)) = Application.Transpose(v)

End Sub
```

Comment: The OP states in the comments that he does not want to use Transpose().

Comment: Thx for the hint; not quite sure - reading the latest comments and without further explanation/edit it's unclear for me if OP actually prefers a simple data transposition or sort of rearranged data :)